# chart.js and chartTrendLine in angular application not compiling

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to **implement a plugin called chartjs-plugin-TrendLine**
into **chart.js** in my angular application.

The plugin is located here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-trendline/v/0.1.1

It just won't pick up correctly.
The problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to get picked up correctly in my component.

```js
This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.
```

Steps:

```bash
npm i chartjs-plugin-trendline
```

(observe node_modules now has version 1.1 installed)

```js
import { Chart, ChartData, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import chartTrendLine from 'chartjs-plugin-trendline'; 
 <<< the error i get is 
This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

... this.lineChartData = {

        labels: value.map(x => x.key),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: " count",
            data: value.map(x => x.value),
            backgroundColor: '#333333',
            trendlineLinear: {
              colorMin: "#3e95cd",
              lineStyle: "dotted|solid",
              width: 1
          }
```

Code sandbox has many examples located here:

https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/chartjs-plugin-trendline

I found this angular example but it is also broken :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-version-3-ygaa31

Any advice or samples of this library in an angular app would be super appreciated.

Comment: Hi, macm could you say what version of angular, node you have?

Comment: Since your goal is to see how imports are working in the stackblitz example project, you can use the `as any` dirty trick to get past typescript errors - that plugin seems to not have implemented type definitions yet anyway. For what it's worth, here's a [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-version-3-aednsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that works with dependencies updated to chart.js 4.4.0 and chartjs-plugin-trendline 2.0.5

Comment: Thank you @kikon. I will try and get this working today. I am using angular 15.